# MSYS Home folder in Windows

Tags: windows, gnu, msys

I'm using MSYS in Windows. 
I need to access a file in MSYS `home` folder.

Where is the `/home/username` folder of `MSYS` mapped to in Windows C:\ folders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sh
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\username
# Also known as
$HOME
# Also known as
~
```